# Can't find package 'rg' (RipGrep) on Fedora 26

Tags: fedora, dnf

As an alternative to `ag` ("the silver searcher"), I'd like to install `rg` (**RipGrep**) on my Fedora 26, but I can't find it with

```
dnf search ripgrep
dnf search rg
```

Do you know a community repository that contains it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Fedora 26, 25, or 24, RipGrep (`rg`) is available from a **copr** repository:

```
sudo dnf copr enable carlwgeorge/ripgrep
sudo dnf install ripgrep
```

If you're a Fedora 27+ user, you can install ripgrep from official repositories:

```
sudo dnf install ripgrep
```

For more information, [here's the GitHub repository for RipGrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep).